# Retrieve extra fields with Graph API using PHP

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create some social dashboard and therefore I want to retrieve my posts from my page. When I use this one to fetch my posts, it doesn't return me all the information I need (e.g 'picture', 'full_picture', 'attachments')

```
$user_posts = $facebook->api('/me/posts', 'GET');
print_r($user_posts);
```

But when I try next one, it still doesn't return me my required information:

```
$user_posts = $facebook->api('/me/posts?{created_time,id,message,full_picture,picture,attachments{url,subattachments},likes{name},comments{from,message,comment_count,user_likes,likes{name}}}', 'GET');

print_r($user_posts);
```

Anyone ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has been asked a long time ago, but maybe useful for someone:

After - `me/posts?` - you need to make sure to put `fields=` and then a list of fields required.

So this would be:

```
$user_posts = $facebook->api('/me/posts?fields={created_time,id,message,full_picture,picture,attachments{url,subattachments},likes{name},comments{from,message,comment_count,user_likes,likes{name}}}', 'GET');

print_r($user_posts);
```